# React - < Input> value is not getting updated on onChange event

Tags: reactjs

I have a Modal which contains controllers (`Input`, `DropDown`, `Textarea`, ...) built dynamically.

I'm trying to achieve a behavior for the `Input` controller `onChange` method, to get the value updated inside the input once the user type something inside.
(I tried with the simple html `input` and with some other libraries `Input` like ant design - but same behavior).

For that purpose, I sat a name for each input controller, and sent the event to `onChange`, then used `setState` to set a state variable with the name of the controller with it's value:

```js
else if (element.Type === TEXT) {
  const inputName = element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
  this.setState({ [inputName]: element.Value }, () =>
    elements.push(
      <td className="view-cell" align="left">
        {element.Name}<br />
        <Input key={element.Id}
          name={inputName}
          style={{ width: '100%' }}
          // label={element.Name}
          defaultValue={element.Value}
          value={this.state[inputName]}
          disabled={!element.Editable}
          // size={element.Width}
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.onInputValueChange(e)
            this.onInputChange(element.Id, element.Name, e.target.value)
          }}
        />
      </td>
    ))
}


onInputValueChange(e) {
  const name = e.target.name
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state[name]);
  });
}
```

The problem is that the change is not reflected on the screen.
What can be the reason? is it the fact that the `setState` is an async action?

To reproduce, you can use this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-ci559) (type something inside text boxes)

Comment: this.state[inputName],
console this value in function where you kept this input field

Comment: I'm printing it inside onInputValueChabge! and the value property is bounded to this value

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-btc16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are rendering your component in a state.
You have your inputs, rendered in an Array, wrapped around html, set as a state. When you are editing some input value, you are updating your state, but not the input array. Some values inside this array change, but not the state containing this array -> this state is not re-rendered and the changes are not displayed.

The easy way to fix this is to transform you input from `controled` to `uncontroled` fields by removing `value={this.state[inputName]}`. You will be able to get the value with `this.state[inputName]`, but you are no longer telling the input what content it should have (meaning you cannot, for example, parse the data like this for a phone number input `+33 1 00 00 00 00` instead of the default `+33100000000`.

The hard way is to re-render your array state on each change (not efficient) by editing your `RuleEditor.js` :

```js
else if (element.Type === TEXT) {
  const inputName = element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");

  /*
  ** NO -> You don't want to set the state for each render -> infinite loop risk
  */
  //this.setState({ [inputName]: element.Value })

  elements.push(
    <td className="view-cell" align="left">
    {element.Name}
    <br />
    <Input
      key={element.Id}
      name={inputName}
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      value={this.state[inputName]}
      disabled={!element.Editable}
      onChange={e => {
        this.onInputValueChange(e);
    }} />
  </td>
);
```

```js
  onInputValueChange(e) {
    const name = e.target.name;
    this.setState(
      {
        [name]: e.target.value
      },
      () => {
        //RE-SETSTATE FOR YOUR HEADER AND MAIN
        this.setState({
          header: this.buildRowsUsing_antD(this.ruleProperties.Parts.Header.Rows),
          main: this.buildRowsUsing_antD(this.ruleProperties.Parts.Main.Rows)
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

For this, defaultValue will not be used. If you want to set a default value, you have to assign `this.state[inputName]` to the default value BEFORE or AFTER rendering the state (not when you are rendering it). Although a not so good but easy way is to do `value={this.state[inputName] || element.Value}`

Answer (score 1):

```
    onInputValueChange(e, index, i) {
      const name = e.target.name;
      let header = this.ruleProperties.Parts.Header.Rows
      header[i].Elements[index].Value = e.target.value
      console.log(header[i], header[i].Elements[index], "valuessssssss");
      this.setState(
        {
          header: this.buildRowsUsing_antD(header),
        },
        () => {
          console.log(header, "dfsaf");
        }
      );
    }

    buildRowsUsing_antD(rows) {
      let localRows = [];
      let elements = [];
      console.log("ressosss", rows);
      rows.map((row, i) => {
        elements = [];
        row.Elements.map((element, index) => {
          // console.log(element.Type);
          if (element.Type === LIST) {
            elements.push(
              <td className="view-cell" align="left">
                {element.Name}
                <br />
                <TreeSelect
                  // className=""
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  // value={element.Value}
                  defaultValue={element.Value}
                  dropdownStyle={{
                    maxHeight: 400,
                    overflow: "auto",
                    zIndex: "10000",
                    position: "absolute"
                  }}
                  treeData={this.buildTreeData_antD(element.Values)}
                  // placeholder={element.Name}
                  // treeDefaultExpandAll
                  // onChange={this.onInputChange(element.Id, element.Name)}
                  onChange={val =>
                    this.onInputChange(element.Id, element.Name, val)
                  }
                />
              </td>
            );
          } else if (element.Type === "Text") {
            //   console.log(".......", element.Value);
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            let inputName = element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
            // this.setState({ [inputName]: element.Value });
            //   this.setState({ [inputName]: element.Value }, () =>
            elements.push(
              <td className="view-cell" align="left">
                {element.Name}
                <br />
                <Input
                  key={element.Id}
                  name={inputName}
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  // className="rounded"
                  // label={element.Name}
                  // defaultValue={element.Value}
                  value={element.Value}//do changes hereeeeeeeeee
                  disabled={!element.Editable}
                  // size={element.Width}
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.onInputValueChange(e, index, i);//pass indexxxxxxxx
                    // this.onInputChange(element.Id, element.Name, e.target.value)
                  }}
                />
              </td>
            );
            //   );
          } else if (element.Type === TEXTAREA) {
            const inputName = element.Name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
            this.setState({ [inputName]: element.Value });
            //   this.setState({ [inputName]: element.Value }, () =>
            elements.push(
              <td className="view-cell-full" width="100%">
                {element.Name}
                <br />
                <TextArea
                  key={element.Id}
                  name={inputName}
                  // className="rounded"
                  componentclass="textarea"
                  rows={5}
                  style={{ width: "100%", resize: "auto" }}
                  // placeholder=""
                  disabled={!element.Editable}
                  defaultValue={element.Value}
                  value={this.state[inputName]}
                  onChange={e => {
                    this.onInputValueChange(e); // this.setState({inputVal: e.target.value})
                    // this.onInputChange(element.Id, element.Name, e.target.value)
                    //TODO - Assuming that text area is only for constraint field
                    //   this.props.ruleChangeCallBack(null, e.target.value);
                  }}
                />
              </td>
            );
            //   );
          } else if (element.Type === BUTTON) {
            elements.push(
              <Button
                key={element.Id}
                // onClick={this.onInputChange(element.Id, element.Name, null)}
                onClick={() => this.onInputChange(element.Id)}
              >
                {element.Value}
              </Button>
            );
          } else if (element.Type === LABEL) {
            elements.push(
              <td className="view-cell-full" align="left">
                {element.Value}
              </td>
            );
          }
        });
        // localRows.push(<div className="view-row">{elements}</div>)
        localRows.push(<tr className="view-row">{elements}</tr>);
      });

      return (
        <table width="100%" className="view-table">
          <tbody>{localRows}</tbody>
        </table>
      );
    }
```

Comment: check the changes i have made , after a big ----- line, you need to update the main array you have used to render the whole JSX by passing the index onChange of input

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already accepted a similar solution, really appreciate your efforts